# Use page.php for front page

Tags: php, page-template, homepage, frontpage

For some reason even when I am selecting a static page for my homepage it is still choosing to load the index.php file.

I would really appreciate your help on this as I would like it to load my own page.php template.

Comment: On this static page that you're assigning (on settings > reading I assume on the dashboard) - are you assigning your custom template to it? http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Selecting_a_Page_Template

Comment: Hi there thank you very much for your response. Yep I am. If I view the page without it being selected as the homepage it works fine. However, when I select it as the homepage it just loads the index.php file

Comment: Did you assign another dummy page for the Posts Page on Settings > Reading? So the default blog posts have a place to be? This may help narrow down the problem: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Front_Page_display

Comment: Are you aware of the `home.php` and `front-page.php` templates? You don't need to use page templates to style the homepage

Comment: Currently I only have a single page built and this is the one that is selected. When I deselect it as the homepage it works fine just not when selected as the front page. Hi Tom in regards to these pages I need to use the page templates as it is a very complex and dynamic theme

Answer (score 0):

if it is "a very complex theme," then there's probably some hook into `template_redirect` malfunctioning. as @TomJNowell mentioned, using `home.php` or `front-page.php` should allow you to override `page.php`, but that's not always preferred (I rarely use them myself), and will not necessarily fix the problem. you don't need to assign a blog page in order for there to be a static front page, so double-check on any hooks into `template_redirect`, and see if that resolves the issue.